# Router // Networking

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking

I want r2 to assign and lease ips to all the other device on the network and r1 to just act as a gateway. I wanna know if this is possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EraQ4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It's technically possible – DHCP leases have a dedicated field ("option") indicating the default gateway's address; it does not have to be the same as the DHCP server's own address (the DHCP server doesn't even need to be *on* a router).

However:

1. It doesn't make much sense to do this a "LAN to WAN" connection. That's how you connect routers when you actually want two networks; R2 will be providing DHCP only to its "LAN" side but never to the "WAN" side.
2. The DHCP server must actually allow this to be configured. Most home routers simply don't offer it as a setting, they always include their own address and that's it. So

So – *technically* – yes, it's perfectly possible. But I don't know whether your specific TP-Link can do this or not. You didn't mention the model, but in general I tend to assume they're not flexible enough, for either of the above points.

Many higher-end routers don't have strictly imposed "LAN/WAN" separation (it's after all mostly artificial), and let you run a DHCP server on any interface with any settings. if R2 had something like OpenWRT/DD-WRT or RouterOS or pfSense, that would certainly work. (In fact even installing `dhcpd` on the NAS would work.)

Comment: Thank you!  Here is the link to TP link router emulator and it's Archer A7 https://emulator.tp-link.com/webpages_a7v5_new/index.html

Comment: Also i cannot change DNS on R1 so if you could elaborate with ip configuration would help.

Comment: Yes, it seems to have that option under _Advanced → Network → DHCP Server → Default Gateway_. However, you will still need to reconnect it in the "LAN to LAN" method.

Comment: Can you at least _completely turn off_ DHCP on R1? That'll be required...

Comment: Yes i can. Does it make any difference in firewall rules if DHCP is being handled by another device?

Comment: No, none whatsoever. If your DHCP offers say the gateway is R1, then all traffic goes via R1.